# centos 7 cronjobs from user root run but cronjobs from user apache dont

Tags: cron, centos, centos7

When I create a cronjob with user root it get runned al fine. But when I switch to user Apache and create a cronjob it doesnt run.

What could cause this? I was thinking about so permission issue maybe but can't figure out what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that cron tries to switch to the user's home directory before executing anything and home directory no exists.

You must create the directory.

A better solution is execute cron with sudo:

```
15 1 26 * * sudo -u apache /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/nextcloud/occ files:scan --path=1645FC94-D50C-4E40-B941-38CA3B88EC0F/files/ExternalStorage
```